# svg tspan problem - chrome vs firefox - multiline text

Tags: svg, tspan

im generating SVG with some **multiline** text using **text > tspan** in svg, and found firefox ignores styling display:none and counts height of hidden element. I intend to hide some of the tspan using responsive media queries in css

Live test:
https://codepen.io/peminator/pen/rNoWVrO

```css
body {
  font-size: 15px;
}

svg tspan.t3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<svg stroke="#CCC" fill="#C00">
          <text>
            <tspan class="t1" x="0" dy="1em">AAA</tspan>
            <tspan class="t2" x="0" dy="1em">BBB</tspan>
            <tspan class="t3" x="0" dy="1em">CCC</tspan>
            <tspan class="t4" x="0" dy="1em">DDD</tspan>
            <tspan class="t5" x="0" dy="1em">EEE</tspan>
          </text>
    </svg>
```

[image]

In Firefox, the space for the hidden tspan is still added.
In Chrome, it is omitted.
What is the corect way to dsiplay such multiline text to look same way, if some lines need to be hidden based on client viewport?

Comment: If using visibility hidden, it behaves better, but maybe someone gets better solution?

Comment: This is a [Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1141224). The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/render.html#Rendered-vs-NonRendered) says "Non-rendered elements...are not considered when performing text layout"

Answer (score 2):

As a quirky workaround you can apply a `font-size:0` to the hidden tspans.

```css
body {
  font-size: 15px;
}

tspan.t3 {
  display: none;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg>
      <text stroke="#CCC" fill="#C00">
        <tspan class="t1" x="0" dy="1em">AAA</tspan>
        <tspan class="t2" x="0" dy="1em">BBB</tspan>
        <tspan class="t3" x="0" dy="1em">CCC</tspan>
        <tspan class="t4" x="0" dy="1em">DDD</tspan>
        <tspan class="t5" x="0" dy="1em">EEE</tspan>
      </text>
</svg>
```